# Issue with Interpreter in PyCharm when creating a new project

Tags: python, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ6yO.png)

I had issue with the already installed python. So I reinstalled it. When I did open my PyCharm and created a new projected it showed me this error.

This was working fine till today morning. Maybe re installation of python steps had some problem and I am confused what has to be done

Comment: I recommend copying the error and pasting it into google to see what other's have done previously to solve this problem.

Comment: Please include a bit more details. What issue did you have earlier? How did you reinstall python?